# in java how to get files in a given directory

Tags: java

I want to write a java code, where given a directory name, I should be able to get all the files starting with list (so something like list*) and read each file one by one (linewise), and do some processing .

What classes are available and recommended to read a directory. Is my option is to read all file names by File.list and then pick the ones which start with list..

Thanks

Comment: You answered your own question. I would use one of the listFiles method, though, since it gives you an array of Files rather than an array of Strings. The FilenameFilter version is probably the most appropriate.

Comment: How does FilenameFilter thing help me with this array of Files?

Comment: You should use it to call listFiles(theFilenameFilter). It would return only the files you're interested in, rather than returning all of them, and force you to filter them afterwards.

Comment: ok, makes more sense. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the most central class would be `File`.

Besides that there are some classes that `File`'s methods need (like `FileFilter` etc.)

You can also try and have a look at utility libraries like [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

Comment: okay, and to complete it, How do I create a BufferedReader wrapper over this File object?

Comment: @p2pnode.. FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName); BufferedReadre read = new BufferedReader(reader);

Comment: @ntc this FileName is a string. But here we are getting File object by listFiles method..?

Comment: @p2pnode.. yeah pass File object and not String (file name);

Comment: @p2pnode Have a look at the `FileReader` JavaDocs. There are constructors for `String` or `File` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can list using a file filter as [described here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.io/FilelistFilesFilenameFilterfilter.htm)